# How can I load a text file from Content?

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-8

I created a small Windows Phone game with XNA, but I have some trouble with loading a text file from Content. I added the text file to my Content project and marked the Build Action to "Content". The static text file should be loaded when the game starts, but I always get an exception in this line of the method:

```
if (File.Exists(filename))
```

> An exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

What is wrong? How can I load a text file from Content?

```
private const string filename = "Level1.txt"; 
public void LoadfromContent() 
    { 
        if (File.Exists(filename)) 
        { 
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filename))) 
            { 
                strs = reader.ReadLine().Split(';'); 
                game1.HowManyEnemies = int.Parse(strs[1]); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58940/including-files-in-an-application-using-xna And my comments on that question?

Comment: I changed the Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer" but that didn't helped. Which code should I use to solve the problem? There is many different code in your links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content pipeline project is for content to be *built* with the content pipeline.

If your file will not be processed by the content pipeline, it needs to go in your main game project. Then follow the instructions from [the link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58940/288) Byte56 gave you. Basically set "Content" and "Copy if newer".

---

The exception you are getting, `MethodAccessException`, is because that API isn't available on WP7. Use Title Storage instead. To open your file, you can use:

```
TitleContainer.OpenStream(filename);
```

See the information on MSDN about [Reading Game Data from Title Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199094.aspx) and [Adding Game Data Files to Title Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434501.aspx).

Comment: Thanx. It works now.